# vuetifyjs selects with 'hide-selected=true' show only listing first 20 items

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drop-down-menu, vuetify.js

[vuetify selects](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects) only showing first 20 items from the list if we set hide-selected=true,

```
  <v-select
        v-bind:items="test_data"
        v-model="test_modal"
        label="Reader permissions"
        multiple
        chips
        deletable-chips
        :counter="test_data.length"
         hide-selected

  ></v-select>
```

see complete code on [codepen here](https://codepen.io/prajin/pen/dyoVebj)

Comment: Please see [v-autocomplete](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes), ***items an be an array of objects or array of strings***, but your sample uses numbers.

Comment: @RichardMatsen If we use string the same thing happens,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also increase the `lastItem` property of VSelect, which controls the length of the virtual list and is initially set to 20.

(Note, the properties of VSelect may change over versions)

Add a ref to the select

```html
<v-select
    ref="select"
    v-bind:items="test_data"
    v-model="test_modal"
    label="Reader permissions"
    multiple
    chips
    deletable-chips
    :counter="test_data.length"
     hide-selected
></v-select>
```

Change the value of lastItem in `mounted()`

```js
mounted() {
  this.$refs.select.lastItem = 200;
},
```

Comment: Yes it does work with vuetify@2.2.15 [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-cookies-lmpec).

Answer (score 4):

Possibly that's a bug in vuetify, and I see you're already [opened issue on github](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/10750) :)

I think this bug is related to internal **virtualizedItems** and **computedItems** properties in vuetify's [VSelect class](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VSelect/VSelect.ts).

Computeditems is an array of items that always cropped to 20 items by default and then 20 more items is added, by example, when you scroll your selectbox. Currently (at least in vuetify 2.2.15) there's no way to manipulate with count of added items.

**There's a quick fix** of your problem - just add 
`menuProps="auto"`
to your v-select. It prevents computedItems from cropping. But keep in mind that this may lead to minor visual changes to v-select component. Besides, **all** of your items will be loaded immediately in v-select component and opening of the component may take longer than usual.